# Close all forms in vb

Tags: vb.net, winforms

How can i close all forms

---

I use wpf vb 2010

To load other form i use like

```
Private frm As MainWindow = New MainWindow
```

to open the window i used `frm.Show()`
and to close it i use `frm.Close()`

---

Now I have two forms like form1 and form2

I want to open form2 when i click on the button - ok it's easy

The Question How can i closed form1 from form2 when i open form2 using button

when i user

```
Private frm As form1 = New form1 
frm.Close()
```

It like a cricle and can't closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project + Properties, Application tab, change Shutdown Mode to "When last form closes".  This ensures that your app won't quit until *all* the windows are closed.

Now you can write code like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim frm As New Form2
    '' Optional: keep it in the same spot
    frm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
    frm.Location = Me.Location
    frm.Size = Me.Size
    '' Display the form
    frm.Show()
    '' Close the current form
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to create a constructor for Form2 that took a reference to an instance of Form1 when created. The new instance of Form2 could keep that reference and close the instance of Form1 when needed.

```
Public Class Form2

    Private Property formOne As Form1

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(Form1 frm)
        formOne = frm
    End Sub

    Public Sub CloseFormOne()
        If formOne != null Then
            formOne.Close()
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```